# Can I change items in jquery dynamically?

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic-data

I have the following jquery.

```
$(function() {
$('div#slideshow').append('<img src="images/forsiden/grans_julebrus.jpg" /><img src="images/forsiden/cappelen_hippo.jpg" /><img src="images/forsiden/capplen_grandmarap.jpg" /><img src="images/forsiden/agm_peace.jpg" /><img src="images/forsiden/cappelein_aboriginee.jpg" />');
...
...
```

I want to add all the image dynamically with php.

```
<?php echo $images; ?>
```

Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JS function is in it's own .js file, then by default you cannot inject PHP code inside.

One way to do it is to hide the filenames in the document using hidden input fields (or hidden divs etc) and use jQuery to get them, or you can use jQuery's AJAX functions to request filenames from a PHP handler.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I forgot how to write PHP code over time, so you'll have to figure that part out for yourself.

I'd write JavaScript inside of PHP. For instance:

```
echo "myImages = new Array();";
```

Then you create a for loop which write this for every picture there is

```
echo "myImages[".$i."] = ".$TheImageSrc;
```

When the js File is loaded, Javascript can access that Array and load the images from it via

```
var images = '';
for (var i=0;i<myImages.length;i++){
   images .= '<img src="'+myImages[i]+'" />';
}
$('div#slideshow').append(images);
```

#### Edit 1

Optimised the JS portion

Comment: That would result in multiple appends happening one right after another. Which causes the browser to redraw after each append.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
$('div#slideshow').append("<?php echo $images; ?>");
});
```

Comment: 1) He may have this in an external JS file, 2) you forgot the quotes and 3) He will need to consider escaping quotes in the injected code.